# How to prevent my site users from deleting files without forbidding them to rename/move?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, groups, access-rights

In my site options, I created a group of users and gave them the following rights : Contribute.
It almost fit my requirements but I would like them not to be able to delete files.

My users being french, the sharepoint settings are in french as well.
There is an authorisation group called "Contribute without delete" that doesn't seem to exist in the english version.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work since when I attribute this authorisation group to my user group, they aren't able to rename/move documents.
If I try to create a custom authorisation group with the same rights, it's the same problem.

At this point, it seems like unchecking either the "Delete element" option or "Delete version" options under
"Modify authorisation level" > "Authorisation from lists" prevent users from renaming/moving documents.

[image: These are the two settings I'm talking about (sorry it's not in english...)]

I'm a bit lost since I've seen another site with a similar configuration working well.
I must have forgotten a setting on this one.
Or is it just a translation problem ?

Could you guys help me to resolve this issue ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. When you rename a file, it's essentially a move operation. It creates a new file with the requested name and the old file is deleted, this is very similar to how Windows file systems work. Here's another explanation by Trevor Seward:

[Why delete permission is required to rename a document in SP Document Library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/why-delete-permission-is-required-to-rename-a-document-in-sp/m-p/46134/highlight/true#M4400)